# What does the arrow on VCC in a BJT bias circuit mean?

Tags: bjt

[image]

At the top, the VCC has arrows on it. What does that mean?

I thought it would be like in other circuits as empty holes that you could attach, but I'm not sure here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arrows have no special pointing significance. The conventional symbols used on schematics include the use of the arrow as a symbol for a power supply connection.

If you look around you will notice that there are a variety of different symbols used for power supply connections on schematics. There are also various ways that the associated voltage rail are labeled. Here is a sample of some of the common types. Note that in my example there is no particular correspondence between the label type and the symbol used. This is by no means an exhaustive list either and you can find other usages as well.

[image]

Comment: All posts were good answers! Thanks! I chose yours because of the image highlighting the different symbols. 

It is just that was the first time I saw the voltage denoted like that and I thought it had some special other meaning. I don't think the textbook explained it either (or I missed it), it just went straight to using it in BJTs.

Answer (score 3):

That up pointing arrow is just a convention to say "I'm connecting here the positive voltage supply.". You can actually find circuits where there's only the arrow and not the label: if you only have one supply that's clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Those symbols just represent a source of voltage.  The arrow is a common representation, but other typical representations include bars, circles, or just a label.

Answer (score 2):

The arrow just a symbol to represent this node VCC .

In Schematics you can have more than one VDC at your circuit, and you can use various symbols to designate each of them.

In [this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-read-a-schematic) document you can see that have some symbols for the schematic documents that are not components, like hte ground symbol. This is one that have more than one symbol too.

[image]